# Accessing NHibernate ActionQueue to check the list of pending commands

Tags: c#, debugging, reflection, nhibernate

I have some very basic code:

```
NHibernate.ISession session = doSomeStuffWithNHibernateSession();
```

Using the object inspector in the Visual Studio debugger, I am able to open the `ActionQueue` of the session object and list all the pending NHibernate commands.

Is there a way to access it programmatically ? Being able to access properties like `InsertionCount` or `HasAnyQueuedAction` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work *(using explicit type names instead of `var` to simplify their finding in NH)*

```
NHibernate.ISession session = ...

// here we get the access to underling implementation
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl sessionImpl = session
    .GetSessionImplementation() as NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl;

// and we can now work with action queue
var actionQueue = sessionImpl.ActionQueue;

// and check it
var count               = actionQueue.InsertionsCount;
var hasAnyQueuedActions = actionQueue.HasAnyQueuedActions;
```

Comment: Great to see that ;) enjoy NHibernate